# NGINX file server not able to serve files beyond 2GB

Tags: kodi, termux

I have setup nginx file server on my old Android phone (Samsung A6). I did this using termux and running nginx on termux. This file server is used to serve media files to Kodi on my android TV.

When I try to play a media file of size>2GB, it plays normally. But, I cannot forward to a point beyond the 2GB data point. Example media file is 4GB and duration of media is 2 hours. I am unable to skip to or resume to any point in the video beyond 1 hour 1 minute.

I setup the same server with the same config in my new phone (Samsung S20FE). Everything works perfectly irrespective of file size.

So, I am guessing there is some hardware limitation that I am unable to understand. Is there a way to solve this? My Samsung A6 can play large videos normally (in MX Player or VLC) but not able to serve via file server.

I have tried splitting the media files to smaller chunks and playing through Kodi but Kodi recognizes it as a single media file and the same problem occurs.

Curl response to the file server (on Samsung Galaxy A6) says Address not serviceable, but does not give this error when the same file is hosted on Samsung S20FE.

```
curl -I http://192.168.1.55:14555/test.mkv


HTTP/1.1 200 OK  
Server: nginx/1.25.3  
Date: Tue, 23 Jan 2024 18:33:24 GMT  
Content-Type: application/octet-stream  
Content-Length: 3106324386  
Last-Modified: Tue, 23 Jan 2024 06:48:51 GMT  
Connection: keep-alive  
ETag: "65af6153-b926bfa2"  
Accept-Ranges: bytes

curl -v -r 2147483348-2147483647 http://192.168.1.55:14555/test.mkv

> Trying 192.168.1.55:14555...  
> Connected to 192.168.1.55 (192.168.1.55) port 14555  
> GET /test.mkv HTTP/1.1  
> Host: 192.168.1.55:14555  
> Range: bytes=2147483348-2147483647  
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0  
> Accept: */*  
>  
< HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content  
< Server: nginx/1.25.3  
< Date: Tue, 23 Jan 2024 18:34:41 GMT  
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream  
< Content-Length: 300  
< Last-Modified: Tue, 23 Jan 2024 06:48:51 GMT  
< Connection: keep-alive  
< ETag: "65af6153-b926bfa2"  
< Content-Range: bytes 2147483348-2147483647/3106324386  
<  
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell  
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output  
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.  
* Failure writing output to destination  
* Closing connection  

curl -v -r 2147483348-2147483649 http://192.168.1.55:14555/test.mkv


* Trying 192.168.1.55:14555...  
* Connected to 192.168.1.55 (192.168.1.55) port 14555  
> GET /test.mkv HTTP/1.1  
> Host: 192.168.1.55:14555  
> Range: bytes=2147483348-2147483649  
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0  
> Accept: */*  
>
< HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable  
< Server: nginx/1.25.3  
< Date: Tue, 23 Jan 2024 18:36:22 GMT  
< Content-Type: text/html  
< Content-Length: 197  
< Connection: keep-alive  
< Content-Range: bytes */3106324386  
<  
<html>  
<head><title>416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable</title></head>  
<body>  
<center><h1>416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable</h1></center>  
<hr><center>nginx/1.25.3</center>  
</body>  
</html>  
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.55 left intact
```

As soon as the curl command requests file beyond the 2GB mark of the file, Nginx gives the 416 error.

I am expecting Nginx to serve large files to Kodi without any issues.

Nginx Config:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    client_max_body_size 0;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       14555;
        server_name  localhost;
        autoindex on;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        directio 1G;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/downloads;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;


    #    }
    #}

}
```

Nginx Build

```
nginx version: nginx/1.25.3
built with OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: 
--prefix=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr 
--crossbuild=Linux:3.16.1:arm 
--crossfile=/home/builder/.termux-build/nginx/src/auto/cross/Android 
--with-cc=arm-linux-androideabi-clang 
--with-cpp=arm-linux-androideabi-cpp 
--with-cc-opt=' -I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include -DIOV_MAX=1024 -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -fstack-protector-strong -Oz' 
--with-ld-opt='-L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -march=armv7-a -fopenmp -static-openmp -Wl,
--enable-new-dtags -Wl,
--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -landroid-glob' 
--with-threads --sbin-path=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/nginx 
--conf-path=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
--http-log-path=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/log/nginx/access.log 
--pid-path=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/nginx.pid 
--lock-path=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/nginx.lock 
--error-log-path=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/log/nginx/error.log 
--http-client-body-temp-path=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/lib/nginx/client-body 
--http-proxy-temp-path=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/lib/nginx/proxy 
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi 
--http-scgi-temp-path=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/lib/nginx/scgi 
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi 
--with-http_auth_request_module 
--with-http_ssl_module 
--with-http_v2_module 
--with-http_gunzip_module 
--with-http_sub_module 
--with-stream 
--with-stream_ssl_module
```

The system (Samsung A6) has a 32 bit processor.

Comment: It is indeed a 32 bit CPU platform limitation and it won't be possible to work around it.

Comment: According to gsmarena.com Samsung A6 (1018) uses an Exynos 7870 Octa with Cortex-A53 cores which are armv8a (64bit). If your OS supports only arm-v7(e) then this is a software problem, not a CPU problem. You can try to unlock the device and find a 64bit custom ROM.